# Evitar duplicar registros mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Me gustaría saber que método utilizar o cual seria la forma correcta de evitar que se dupliquen los registros de mi base de datos mysql, esta base recibe cada 10 minutos datos de un sitio externo del cual se extrae la informacion mediante un software de minería. 
solo son 200 datos que se repiten cada 10 minutos
mi tabla contiene los siguientes campos:
id, folio, origen, destino, producto, transporte, fecha de facturación y estatus del pedido, estos dos últimos datos son los importantes, sin embargo un cliente puede tener 3 pedidos y cuando se factura el producto el sistema en automático cambia el valor del folio a 0.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Unique es tu amigo.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar **WHERE NOT EXISTS**

Supongamos que tenemos esta tabla en la DB:

select * from user;

```
+--------+-------------+
| name   | lastname    |
+--------+-------------+
| Wanda  | maximoff    |
| Pietro | maximoff    |
+--------+-------------+
```

Y queremos agregar otro registro diferente a Pietro, utilizamos lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO user (`name`, `lastname`) 
SELECT 'Pietro', 'quicksilver' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM user WHERE name = 'Pietro'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Otra opción también válida, es que selecciones los campos que te sean importantes, y los marques como index del tipo UNIQUE, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `lastname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `age` INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `my_indice` (`name`,`lastname`) USING BTREE
);
```

En este caso, no podrán haber registros repetidos con el mismo par **name+lastname**

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda usando un el indice ya no se duplican los registros, mi otra duda es la informacion la recibe la base de datoses de manera automática cada 15 minutos y tengo 2 campos que son el estatus de un pedido y otro con fecha y hora, como puedo configurar que estos 2 campos si se actualicen? gracias de antemano.

Comment: En ese caso, tu query cambia. Tienes que usar o un REPLACE o un ON DUPLICATE KEY
Te dejo link a una consulta que ya hicieron:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243630/en-mysql-no-actualiza-on-duplicate-key-update?answertab=active#tab-top