# En MySQL no actualiza ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO contactos
       (iduser, tipo, codigo, nombre, dni_nif )
VALUES
       ('1','cliente','1','Juan','500000'),
       ('1','cliente','2','Maria','500001'),
       ('2','cliente','1','Sara','500002')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
       codigo = codigo,
       iduser = iduser;
```

En **MySQL**: `iduser+codigo` (clave única)

**iduser** = codigo asignado al cliente

**codigo** = clave del contacto de cada cliente

Tengo la anterior consulta, la primera vez que se ejecuta funciona bien, pero si el cliente decide volver a subir los datos (**excel**) para actualizar los existentes y/o agregar nuevos clientes, no consigo que actualice los que ya existen.

¿Donde está el problema?

Comment: Cual es la diferencia entre esta pregunta y la que hiciste ayer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mario.

Por lo que veo en la consulta que haces, estás intentando modificar los campos 
**codigo** e **id_user** en el update. Lo cual no tiene sentido, ya que les asignaría los mismos, valores.
Allí lo que tienes que utilizar son el resto de los campos: **tipo, nombre y dni_nif** que son los que tienes que actualizar.

Supongamos que tenemos esta tabla:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
| id | name        | team                        |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | Logan       | x-men                       |
|  2 | Storm       | x-men                       |
|  3 | Beast       | x-men                       |
|  4 | Quicksilver | Brotherhood of Evil Mutants |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------+
```

Y queremos insertar o actualizar (como lo que estás haciendo), tenemos dos opciones:

**1 - REPLACE**

El comando replace, lo que hace es ejecutar un insert, pero si encuentra que el registro que se quiere insertar tiene un índice que ya existe (primary o unique), lo borra primero eh inserta el nuevo. 
Por ejemplo:

```
REPLACE INTO `mutants` (`id`, `name`, `team`)  VALUES (4, 'Quicksilver', 'x-men');
-- Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.09 sec)
```

Y el resultado será:

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id | name        | team  |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | Logan       | x-men |
|  2 | Storm       | x-men |
|  3 | Beast       | x-men |
|  4 | Quicksilver | x-men |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

**2 - INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

Para nuestro caso sería:

```
INSERT INTO `mutants` (`id`, `name`, `team`)  VALUES (4, 'Quicksilver', 'x-men')   
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE team='inhumans', name='Peter Maximoff';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.08 sec)
-- Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.07 sec)
```

Y el resultado que nos da:

```
+----+----------------+----------+
| id | name           | team     |
+----+----------------+----------+
|  1 | Logan          | x-men    |
|  2 | Storm          | x-men    |
|  3 | Beast          | x-men    |
|  4 | Peter Maximoff | inhumans |
+----+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: Genial !! No conocía REPLACE, me sirve, muchas gracias.

Comment: hay que tener cuidado en el replace, ya que en el caso de tener una id auto incrementable, puede que te ponga una id totalmente distinta cuando borra el registro, entonces las claves foráneas que tengas no serían ya iguales y se perdería información

Comment: @Juanant yo prefiero el on duplicate pero al ser una subida masiva de cientos de lineas, como puedo especificar en cada linea las keys para actualizar?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas usando una consulta `INSERT` para modificar los datos existentes, y deberías usar una consulta `UPDATE`, ya que `INSERT` siempre va a intentar insertar los datos a la tabla, y si hay claves duplicadas te salta el error que nos comentas ([`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/)).

Deberías ejecutar una consulta similar a la siguiente cuando se trata de modificar los datos existentes en una tabla:

```
UPDATE contactos SET tipo = 'cliente', nombre = 'Juan', dni_nif = '500000' 
WHERE iduser = '1' AND codigo = '1'
```

Comment: Esto no es posible, cuando el cliente quiera subir su base de datos con más de 1000 líneas, no sabe cual existe y cual es nuevo. Debe haber una forma para que el propio MySQL detecte que si la fila existe que la actualice y sino pues la crea. Para estos casos existe ON DUPLICATE KEY.

Comment: @Ruiz86 Tienes razón, solo que cuando en el ON DUPLICATE KEY pones codigo = codigo, debe ser el valor que quieres actualizar, por ejemplo `nombre = 'María'` y claro, si es una cadena de texto va entre comillas.

Comment: @Juanant y me actualizará sólo los que coincida iduser+codigo no? Si encuentra por ejemplo otro *nombre = 'María'* pero es otro iduser+codigo, no lo modifica, no?

Comment: @Ruiz86 esto que quieres hacer solo funciona si en base de datos, codigo y iduser son claves primarias de verdad, de lo contrario el ON DUPLICATE KEY no tiene ni idea de lo que debe hacer. Otro consejo es que en lugar de usar dos valores para clave única, utilices una clave AUTO_INCREMENT. Te dejo un ejemplo en inglés de lo que intentas hacer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714587/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-for-multiple-rows-insert-in-single-query

Comment: La clave autoincrement existe, se llama *id* pero el cliente no tiene acceso a ella cuando va a subir su excel. Es interna de la BD. Lo único que puedo controlar para que no haya campos duplicados en el caso de que el cliente suba varias veces su excel es que no se dupliquen iduser+codigo, no se si me explico.

Comment: La columna id si es primaria, las otras dos únicas.

Comment: @Juanant acabo de visitar tu enlace y tras revisarlo todo punto por punto me he dado cuenta que me faltaba una coma en el ON UPDATE. Gracias, tu respuesta también me vale y voy a usarla en vez de REPLACE.

Comment: @Ruiz86 perfecto, a seguir desarrollando entonces :)